# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion

This is one of the [7 essential questions for a stack exchange site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/). How do we promote our site so more people will join the conversation?

For my part, I was sure to mention it on our radio show, [The Amp Hour](http://theamphour.com). Hopefully that will bring some more people here. I plan to mention it again in the future.

How do you plan to get the word out? Should we get a badge to put on individuals' sites to say they participate here? (Like on Chiphacker).

Answer (score 6):

We had an opportunity to feature the site on http://www.eeweb.com so I provided copy and permission to do so:

http://www.eeweb.com/websites/electrical-engineering-stack-exchange

[image: eeweb-mentions-electrical-engineering-se]

Comment: That's how I found out about it.  I'm spending some time this weekend getting to know the site.  It's rather confusing at first.  The name "stackexchange" isn't doing you any favors.  To me cutsy names are a turnoff.  I'd rather have a name that comes as close as possible to describing what you get.  Maybe if just the "stack" were dropped it would make sense.  When I hear "stack" in a technical context, the first thing that comes to mind is a stack inside a computer, but that makes absolutely no sense in this context.

Comment: @olin welcome! The genesis of the network is http://stackoverflow.com but we are expanding into other topics, thus the "stack". We think it works as a metaphor for a "stack" of answers under a question, sorted by upvotes (our default).

Comment: it's easier to say than 'priorityqueueexchange', too

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Yeah we definitely need a real name.  x.stackexchange.com is a terrible name.

Comment: @endolith: Yes, cutesy "in" names cater to insiders while basically telling outsiders they don't belong.  I know there is a history behind the "stack" names, but if the owners of this site want to expand they have to get over that.  Nobody *outside* gives a crap about how your name evolved, and non-descriptive names of off-putting and exclusionary.  A name is a 300 ms opportunity to tell someone what you are and what you do.  If you miss that chance, they'll just walk away because they don't know it might be suitable.  The site owners need to grow up a bit.

Comment: @olin well, domain names are a difficult (and extremely expensive) problem. If you find one that's available for less than a few million dollars that you like, feel free to send it along.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is becoming a very cliche method, but do we have a facebook group I do not know about?

I think chiphacker had one, but we should think about using a facebook group to promote the site and show public support that our friends can see.

Answer (score 3):

In other communities I regularly redirect people here when it is a perfect question for ER.

Chris and a few others have probably seen me occasionally do this on reddit. I think informing people that there is a site designed for asking hobbyist questions where they can reward people for helping and the community will vote to inform them of relative quality of the answers.

Comment: Yeah, it's tough because you don't want to seem like you're putting down another community but at the same time we want more people here and obviously like ER better ;-)

Comment: I can understand how this might be tough on other forums across the net, but I frequently do this on other StackExchange sites without any qualms whatsoever, and I think we should all do the same.  Be careful and gently recommend our site on other electronics forums, but feel free to be vocal about this being the better place to ask on StackOverflow and friends.

Comment: I use it on other forums where people are asking debugging questions and questions that clearly have one clear answer. I also push it heavily if they are having a hard time telling the good answers apart.

Answer (score 3):

When promoting the site, we're going to need an identity.

**We are electronics.stackexchange.com**

We might agree on a logo or tagline later, but we are electronics.stackexchange.com.

Chiphacker is dead, long live electronics.stackexchange.com.

*No more shout-outs for chiphacker!* :-)

Comment: Out with the old, in with the new. I still miss chiphacker, I liked the site name.

Comment: Should E&R be used as an abbreviation?  electronics.stackexchange.com is a mouthful.

Comment: I think E&R is a bit meaningless. The question probably deserves an entire question.

Comment: Yeah, I use E&R as shorthand when talking to SO, and others here, but I would not use it anywhere else.

Comment: I liked chiphacker, coz I always thought it was fun to pronounce it "chi-phacker"!

Answer (score 3):

Do you think it'd be a good idea to promote this site around my school, and encourage my Electrical Engineering classmates, professors and TAs to participate?

Comment: I think tha promoting is always a good idea